# laravel eager Load performance

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have a question about eager load about , add constraint first or after is better in performance. For example,

```
User::with('userinfo')->find($id)
```

and

```
User::where('id',$id)->with('userinfo')->get()
```

How much difference of its performance?

Comment: `->get() `  will load all result, and `->find `only show 1 result , if the result is 1000 rows, so `->find` is 1000 times faster and lighter

Comment: but i have where query builder for constraint the user_id =1

Answer (score 0):

In your instance, you are only running 2 queries in both examples. `find($id)` is exactly the same as `where('id', $id)` because primary keys are unique. The order of `with()` does not matter as Laravel will still execute the same queries.

Where eager loading matters is lets say you have a controller that retrieves all 20 users in your database

```
User::get()
```

and a blade view that outputs their info

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   {{ $user->userInfo->(some property) }}
@endforeach
```

Your blade view will have to make a query for each users info, giving you a classic N+1 problem (1 query to fetch all users and 20 queries fetching each users info). That is where eager loading comes to the rescue, allowing you to fetch 20 users with their info in just 2 queries.